# ASCII code didn't work at wa.me custom message llink

Tags: wordpress, backend, whatsapp, web-development-server

I have a link that will redirect to WhatsApp with a form that has been filled in, but if I add the filed name to the WhatsApp code, the ASCII code for enter doesn't work, what's the solution?
[https://wa.me/-?text=name:[field](https://wa.me/-?text=name:%5Bfield) id="name"]%0Aemail:[field id="email"]%0Acompany:[field id="company"]%0Amessage:[field id="message"]

i removed [field id:-] and the ascii code will, but i want to keep adding [field id:-]